# Setting UAC to require administrator priviledge using PyInstaller doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

My problem is somewhat similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964909/setting-uac-to-requireadministrator-using-pyinstaller-onefile-option-and-manifes).

I have created a windows executable from a python program using PyInstaller with `--onedir` and `--manifest` options. Running the application does ask for administrator privilege. However it throws an `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` for the following piece of code inside the application:

```
import os

_PATH = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')
f = open(os.path.join(_PATH, 'Foo', 'Bar.txt'), 'w')
f.close()
```

Strangely enough the following piece of code outputs `1` as expected:

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
```

I am using `Python 2.7.10 amd64`. In the linked question someone pointed out that `Python 2.7.10 amd64` doesn't work with the Manifest file. I also tried the most upvoted answer in that question, editing the PyInstaller library, but that didn't help. Did anyone else face this?